# How to use FXCanvas with SWT Java 8

Tags: java, maven, javafx, swt

I am trying to integrate JavaFX inside of an SWT application using FXCanvas. For reference, I am following [this oracle guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx-swt_interoperability.htm)

Within my IDE this chunk of code displays an error

```
/* Create an FXCanvas */
final FXCanvas fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.NONE) {

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
        getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
        int width = (int) getScene().getWidth();
        int height = (int) getScene().getHeight();
        return new Point(width, height);
    }
};
```

Error:

*(yes, I have imported the correct Point class: `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point`*):

```
'computeSize(int, int, boolean)' in 'Anonymous class derived from javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas' clashes with 'computeSize(int, int, boolean)' in 'javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

**However, I don't think this is the root cause**... Because when I try to build the project (**maven**) I get this error:

`package javafx.embed.swt does not exist`. Which I believe is the true issue.

So after doing some research I have checked a few things, firstly, the jfxswt jar looks like it should be accessible:

[image]

and if I open the JAR, you can see FXCanvas is there:
[image]

I even tried adding the JAR manually as a library to my module, still doesn't work.

Here is my pom.xml, (i've intentionally anonymized certain info)

I will also mention that I have tried this in a fresh project without any maven dependencies, and just adding swt and such as libraries manually with the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId></groupId>
        <artifactId></artifactId>
        <version></version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name></name>
    <description></description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>jface</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-I20070606-0010</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Am I missing something, any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml`? (I assume it is a maven project as you tagged it with that.)

Comment: @Gebezs added the pom and some more info to the original post.

Comment: What java version does the `pom.xml` defines? Is it defined in the parent? I am looking for the `maven.compiler.target` and `maven.compiler.source` values and the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration. As the classes should be included in the jdk and the same error occurs with a zero-dependency module that's my best guess. The `mvn help:effective-pom` should output the merged configuration.

Comment: @Gebezs ```<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>``` Both are set to 1.8, as is my jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `jfxswt.jar` file to your classpath for compile and for execution.

This can be done by using the system scope as that jar file is part of your JDK under the `jre/lib` directory.

```xml
<dependency>
    <!-- GroupId/ArtifactId/Version doesn't matter unless it clashes. -->
    <groupId>jfxswt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfxswt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxswt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This will instruct maven to add the `jre/lib/jfxswt.jar` to the classpath. This could cause an issue if someone uses different JDK what has that jar in other places but for Java 8 you should be okay.

You have to add the `jfxswt.jar` to your classpath when you execute your application.

In maven you can use the exec plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>twobuttons.TwoButtons</mainClass>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <!-- The run environment must configure the system jar. -->
            <element>${java.home}/lib/jfxswt.jar</element>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Notes**:

The system scope is deprecated in maven in favor of installing files to repositories. The solution above works fine at the moment.

The content of the `jfxswt.jar` can be part of some SWT libraries unfortunately I am not familiar with SWT. If you can find that jar in a Maven repo than just include that instead of messing with the system scope.

The `twobuttons.TwoButtons` class is from the tutorial you mentioned.